# How to Set Up Driver Support for I2S Audio Codec

Tags: gpio, audio, driver, alsa, i2s

I am building a I2S audio codec using an ADAU1781 chip, which will communicate with the Pi via the GPIO pins. In my research I have found that there is an ASoC driver built into the Raspberry Pi kernel.

1. Does this mean the driver is included in a standard build of Raspbian Jessie?
2. What additional steps do I need to talk to see that the codec is recognized by alsa?

Comment: I have done something similar using the adafruit class D mono amp. Maybe the tutorial is also suitable for your chip: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-max98357-i2s-class-d-mono-amp